# Remove SVN external reference on repository

Tags: svn, svn-externals

As part of my deployment scripts I do an svn copy from the trunk to the tags directory, which is in turn exported to our server.  In a current project thats in development i'll be using svn externals to reference some files from another project.

Upon deployment i'd like to remove that reference and save a local copy with the code.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I realise I could do an svn export then check that in to the repo but it seems overly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the SVN externals reference pointing to another project within the same repository? If so, you can remove the svn:externals property, and instead `svn copy` the project directly under the code.

If the reference is to an external project, I would strongly consider making it a reference to a tag of that project, not the trunk. That way you will have more control of when you want to refer to new versions of the external project. Each of the copies under your tags directory will refer to a specific version of the external project files.